# Will C# Take(k) extension method execute a complete previous GroupBy in sequence?

Tags: c#, linq, iterator, extension-methods

I was "playing" around with LINQ and testing some stuff and something came to my attention.

Let's suppose I have this "lazy" implementation for the `GroupBy` extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> GroupByA<TSource, TKey>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        //To avoid duplicate groups
        List<TKey> grouping = new List<TKey>();
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (!grouping.Contains(keySelector(item)))
            {
                grouping.Add(keySelector(item));
                Group<TKey, TSource> g = new Group<TKey, TSource>(
                    keySelector(item),
                    source.Where(x => keySelector(x).Equals(keySelector(item)))
                );
                Console.WriteLine("Returning group");
                yield return g; //yield returning a complete group
            }
        }
    }
```

Note: Assume `Group<TKey, TSource>` implements `IGrouping<TKey, TSource`

I was wondering, What happens if execute this?

```
var groups = students.GroupByA(x => x.Group).Take(2);
```

Note: `students` is `List<Student>`.

**Will `.Take(2)` force the complete `.GroupByA(x=>x.Group)` execution or somehow will it consume one group at a time until it counts `2`?** Either way **Why?**

PS: I tried using my own implementation for:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeA<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
```

like this:

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> TakeA<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int count)
    {
        int iter = 0;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (iter == count)
                yield break;
            yield return item;
            iter++;
        }
    }
```

But I am pretty sure that way causes the `GroupBy` to execute completely before calling `TakeA`. I don't know if it is my way of implementing it or somehow *original* `Take` does something else different.

Comment: But you can just see yourself. Put breakpoint \ Console.WriteLine into `GroupByA` and see what is being called and when.

Comment: `.Take(2)` will call `.MoveNext` twice on the iterator and then abandon it. In other words, everything up to and including `yield` happens twice, but the `foreach` will not complete. This is true for `TakeA` as well (which closely resembles the framework's implementation).

Comment: Of course the complete source sequence must be enumerated to build the groups, but then `Take(2)` just takes 2 of all groups. Your implementation is "too lazy". You don't build the complete groups, so you should not yield them right now.

Comment: [Here's the .NET implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f4af552327cd38c7,references). You see that it first creates the groups and fills a collection(`Lookup<TKey, TElement>`). So `GroupBy` is actually not very lazy/not really using deferred execution.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, So, are you saying and seeing the link, the real `GroupBy` implementation **does** executes the complete query before executing `Take()` (and therefore not really using deferred execution). And also, my `GroupByA` does use deferred execution cause of its *lazyness*?

Comment: Your `GroupByA` assumes that its input `IEnumerable` can be iterated multiple times by using that `Where` expression on it internally. The framework one will not be built on that assumption and will guarantee to only enumerate `source` once.

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX you can't evaluate an operation like `OrderBy`,  `GroupBy`, `Max()` without inspecting *all* data in order to decide what goes in what order or bucket. The last item in a sequnce may have to be placed first. You can avoid this only if the input is already sorted so you know eg that if you see a new key value, the current group is done. By using eager evaluation GroupBy *saves* time.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `GroupBy` doesn't need the input to be consumed before it returns the first, or several, groups. It is implemented like that, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It only has to consume the input looking for keys belonging to the first group if someone is *iterating* the first group. It could potentially return the second group by consuming the second item.

Comment: For more on the partially-deferred implementation of GroupBy, see https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/01/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-21-groupby/

Comment: I'm confused by the question; it sounds like you are asking "I wrote this code; what happens when I run it?" You could find out by running it.

Comment: @EricLippert, I did run it, but wasn't completely sure If the framework `GroupBy` was as `lazy` as I thought, someway along my testing I did a `... source.Count<T>();` inside my `TakeA()` and found my `GroupBy` forcing to create all groups, and again was confused. Just trying to unravel the (maybe-not-so) mysteries of LINQ, query operators and deferred execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# compiler translates your code into a state machine. That is, it creates a new class behind the scenes with state and behavior needed for iterating the student list. Each time you call the code you get an instance of this class.

> Will .Take(2) force the complete .GroupByA(x=>x.Group) execution

Looking at the full `students.GroupByA(x => x.Group).Take(2)` expression, .Net is able to use the new class instance created by the `GroupByA()` with the `Take()` function, and you can think of it as execution only continues until the second time your code hits the `yield` line, but no further.

However, the nature of a GROUP BY operation is you must loop through the entire dataset to know the attributes of your group, meaning even though you only see the second `yield` expression, the `source.Where()` call still has to look at your entire data set and make for at least a `O(n*m)` operation... every time you identify a new group you go through the entire dataset again.

It should be possible to write a `O(n)` GROUP BY operation using a Dictionary rather than a List for finding new groups and accumulating aggregate info in the Dictionary values as you go. You might want to see if you can manage that. Of course, the catch is with small values for `n` (small source list sizes) the hash calculations and lookups can cost more than the sequence iterations.

Comment: Why `O(n log n)`? Does it do something interesting? I was thinking it was linear. That way, The worst-case for **my implementation** `GroupByA` was `O(n^3)` cause -Iterating over the complete source -For each element see if its key has already been found -Then the `Where()` call to find all elements in that group. In the worst-case, there will be `n` groups (`n` being the source's length) Am I wrong?

Comment: It's `O(n log n)` because the `Where()` function inside the `foreach` loop also loops over the entire dataset. Without the `if()` condition it would be `O(n*n)` (n-squared... can't superscript in a comment).

Comment: @DarK_FirefoX laziness and complexity aren't related. An operation like GroupBy has to inspect all the data in order to return even the first grouping *unless* the data is already ordered by the key. `Enumerable.GroupBy` doesn't differentiate between Enumerable and OrderedEnumerable sources though. If you don't want to process all data, use a custom implementation and ensure the input is pre-ordered, eg by using an `ORDER BY` clause in the SQL query that returned it or by sorting the input file

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, I'm sorry, you said "at least a `O(n log n)`". But the **worst-case** still `O(n^3)`? right?

Comment: I don't think so. `n^3` usually involves another level of nested loop, without any filtering in the loops: `foreach(i in seq) { foreach(j in seq) { foreach(k in seq) { //... } } }`. You don't want that. `n^3` is pretty bad. What you have is effectively: `foreach(i in seq) { if (...) { foreach (j in seq) { //... } } }` This might be `O(n*m)` rather than `O(n log n)`... it's been a while since working with this in my undergrad days. `O(n log n)` might require the inner loop to start iterating at the current position of the outer loop.

Comment: I know: But in my `GroupByA()` i have the `foreach (var item in source) { ... if (!grouping.Contains(keySelector(item))) { .... source.Where(x => keySelector(x).Equals(keySelector(item)) ... ) ...}` Isn't the `Contains()` `O(n)` in the worst-case, and so the `Where()`?. PS: Filtering not decrease in a *raw* manner the execution time.

Comment: `Contains()` and `Where()` are both `n`. But `Where()` is `n` in all cases. `Contains()` can be `1` in the best case and `n` in the worst, with an `n/2` average... but that reduces to just `n`.  The thing is, they happen in sequence rather than nesting in a loop. So they don't multiply each other. It's `2n`, which still reduces to just `n` for big-O purposes. Additionally, the `.Contains()` call is only looking at the identified groups. It's not looking at your source data. That's part of leading me to think it could be `O(n*m)` rather than `O(n log n)`. Again... it's been a long time.

Comment: ... continuing... **Worst** case is `O(n*n)` (n-squared), if every item is it's own group, and you could do as well as `O(n)` if every item is in the same group. Based on that, I am going to revise the answer from `O(n log n)` to `O(n*m)`.

Comment: You are **completely right* It is `O(n*m)` where `m` would be how many groups there are. I was misled by the `if(..)` and didn't notice there were nested but in a sequence.

Comment: Glad we're on the same page. Now go build the `O(n)` version I talked about :)